# Can I use allowDiscUse in a SpringData repository with a collation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to get a List of items from my MongoDB collection with the help of a Repository with custom Query. When I call the Method over my REST interface with Postman, I get the following error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-20T09:53:49.328+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Query failed with error code 96 and error message 'Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 96 and error message 'Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.' on server localhost:27017",
    "path": "/api/path/to/call"
}
```

My Mongo Repository (anonymized)

```
public interface NameRepository extends MongoRepository<NameItem, String> {

    @Query(collation = "{ 'locale': 'de','strength': 1, 'alternate': 'shifted'}")
    List<NameItem> findByName(String name);
}
```

I want to use "allowDiscUse" to not getting the maximum bytes error. Is this possible with repositories, or do I have to use mongoTemplate, when i want to use this option?

Comment: `allowDiskUse` is used with Aggregation queries only.

Comment: i guess, there is no way, i can get the aggregation to work with the  @query annotation?

Comment: You can use the @Aggregation. I think the query you have can be reworked as an aggregation query.